# google sheet's modified time in react js using tabletop

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets-api, last-modified, tabletop.js

I'm using tabletop in order to get data from google sheets in react js. I don't want to fetch data each time when the page is loaded instead I wish to get sheet's data by analyzing last modified time of the sheet and that of the time I last fetched data. is it possible in tabletop or by any means is this process possible? please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### AFAIK this is not possible with Tabletop or the Sheets API

You would need to use the:

### Drive API

Specifically you would need to get the [`files`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) resource which has, amongst many other fields:

```js
{
  "kind": "drive#file",
  "id": string,
  "name": string,
  "mimeType": string,
  "description": string,
  "starred": boolean,
  "trashed": boolean,
  "viewedByMe": boolean,
  "viewedByMeTime": datetime,
  "createdTime": datetime,
  "modifiedTime": datetime,
  "modifiedByMeTime": datetime,
  "modifiedByMe": boolean
}
```

To use this with your JavaScript, I would recommend first getting the quickstart working:

> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js

Then adapt it to your needs.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. could you please help me with creating a spreadsheet using javascript and return the URL of the sheet?